# Commutative diagram Beamer pauses using \xymatrix

Tags: beamer, commutative-diagrams, pause, xymatrix

I want to make a commutative diagram that has pauses ingrained in them using the \xymatrix command.  I want to build up a diagram in my presentation piece-by-peace, but I'm not very sure how to make it happen.  Here's a picture of what I want to make.  [image]

However, I don't want to make it appear all at once.  I want to start from $X$, then show $f_0$ going to $Y_0$, then show $f_1$ going to $Y_1$, and then show $g_0$ going from $Y_1$ to $Y_0$, etc...

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Here's a mini version of my file code for what I made:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
%\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\of}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\ofb}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\ofc}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\ofi}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\ofa}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\pause
\xymatrix{
& & & & & & X \ar[dllllll]|-{f_0} \ar[dlllll]|-{f_1} \ar@{.>}[dllll] \ar[dlll]|-{f_k} \ar@{.>}[dll] \ar[dl]|-{f_{i-1}} \ar[dr]|-{\color{red}{f_i}}\\
Y_0 & \ar[l]^{g_0} Y_1 & \ar@{.>}[l] \cdots & \ar[l]^{g_{k-1}} Y_k & \ar[l]^{g_k} \cdots & \ar[l]^{g_{i-2}} Y_{i-1} & & \ar[ll]^{\color{red}{g_{i-1}}} \color{red}{Y_i}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry that the code isn't pasting correctly.

Comment: Information about code formatting: [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I'm trying to correctly paste the code in but it only produces the first line of code

Comment: @gorzardfu Select all the code _then_ press the `{}` button (note: your code is just a snippet, not a minimal working example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\uncover` or similar inside your `\xymatrix`. For example to uncover `Y_i`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\xymatrix{
& & & & & & X \ar[dllllll]|-{f_0} \ar[dlllll]|-{f_1} \ar@{.>}[dllll] \ar[dlll]|-{f_k} \ar@{.>}[dll] \ar[dl]|-{f_{i-1}} \ar[dr]|-{\color{red}{f_i}}\\
Y_0 & \ar[l]^{g_0} Y_1 & \ar@{.>}[l] \cdots & \ar[l]^{g_{k-1}} Y_k & \ar[l]^{g_k} \cdots & \ar[l]^{g_{i-2}} Y_{i-1} & & \ar[ll]^{\color{red}{g_{i-1}}} \uncover<2->{\color{red}{Y_i}}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't seem to work.  It still reveals the entire diagram instead of piece-by-piece.

Comment: @gorzardfu The above examples reveals only the `Y_i`, everything else is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: ohhh I see now.  I didn't notice that at first, thanks a ton!